# Returning cursor results

Tags: postgresql, cursor, resultset, plpgsql, sql-returning

I have the following procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findKNN()
RETURNS Text AS $body$
DECLARE
    cur refcursor;
    tempcur refcursor;
    gid_ integer;
    _var1 integer;
    _var2 integer;
BEGIN
    open cur for execute('select gid from polygons');
    loop
    fetch cur into gid_;
    open tempcur for SELECT g1.gid , g2.gid FROM polygons AS g1, polygons AS g2
    WHERE g1.gid = gid_  and g1.gid <> g2.gid ORDER BY g1.gid , ST_Distance(g1.the_geom,g2.the_geom)
        LIMIT 5;
             loop
                 fetch tempcur into _var1 , _var2;
                     -- how to return _var1 , _var2 here ? 
                 end loop;
          end loop;
                close cur;
    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I don't know how to return the result out of this procedure. The query returns 5 rows for each execution within outer cursor loop. How can I retrieve these five rows for each query execution?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are trying to do something more complicated that is not in your question, you can radically simplify to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_knn()
    RETURNS TABLE(gid1 integer, gid2 integer)  AS
$body$
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT g1.gid , g2.gid
    FROM   polygons g1
    JOIN   polygons g2 ON g1.gid <> g2.gid
    -- WHERE  g1.gid = <some_condition>  -- ???
    ORDER  BY g1.gid, st_distance(g1.the_geom, g2.the_geom)
    LIMIT  5;

END;
$body$    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or even:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_knn()
    RETURNS TABLE(gid1 integer, gid2 integer)  AS
$body$
    SELECT g1.gid , g2.gid
    FROM   polygons g1
    JOIN   polygons g2 ON g1.gid <> g2.gid
    -- WHERE  g1.gid = <some_condition>  -- ???
    ORDER  BY g1.gid, st_distance(g1.the_geom, g2.the_geom)
    LIMIT  5;
$body$    LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM x.find_knn();
```

The manual about [Returning From a Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).
The manual about [CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).

---

#### Retrieve a small slice of a huge join

(Answer to comment.)
There is many ways to pick a small slice of a huge join without actually evaluating the whole join. In most cases you don't even have to worry about it. For instance, run this at home:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM   huge_tbl t1
CROSS  JOIN huge_tbl t2
LIMIT  5
```

You will see that only 5 rows will be processed, *not* the whole cross join.
The same is true for a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   huge_tbl t1
    CROSS JOIN huge_tbl t2
    )
SELECT *
FROM   a
LIMIT  5
```

Some limitations apply. I quote the [excellent manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html):

> PostgreSQL's implementation evaluates only as many rows of a WITH
>   query as are actually fetched by the parent query.

To make absolutely sure, you could apply the `LIMIT` (or a fitting `WHERE` clause) at the source:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT * FROM huge_table LIMIT 1) t1
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT * FROM huge_table LIMIT 5) t2;
```

Comment: +1  At least 90% of the time that I see a cursor used, it is not the best solution to the problem at hand. Any time anyone is considering use of a cursor, they should step back, and see what alternatives are available.

Comment: @kgrittn: Exactly! Of the rare occasions where a cursor is the best solution, again, the majority is best off with the built-in cursor of a [FOR LOOP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , Sir , that is what i dont want. your solution is perfectly correct, but i dont want to perform the JOIN between two tables altogether, because the table is large and it really murders the query execution. What i need is to iterate the table polygon table , and for each gid , i want to minimize the load on JOIN operation using where condition. Thats why i used outer cursor for this purpose. 
I think you should refer to this : http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor

Comment: @AbhishekSagar: I added a bit to my answer. If that does not solve your problem, clarify your question what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , my problem is , i have a polygon table. For every polygon, i need to find the find nearest polygons in terms of euclidean distance.